# Codename One - Add EventListener to an image drawn in the Glasspane

Tags: codenameone

I wrote the following method to add an icon that stays "over" the app, in the Glasspane. My question is how to add an event triggered by taping the icon. For example, if the user taps the helpImage icon (as drawn in the following code), over the app will appear a Form to contact the technical support (the below form should be blur).

```
public static void addOverlayIcon(Form current) {
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TechnicalSupportIcon");
    Image helpImage = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LIVE_HELP, s);
    current.setGlassPane((g, rect) -> {
        int x = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() - helpImage.getWidth() - Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1);
        int y = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1);
        g.drawImage(helpImage, x, y);
    });
    current.revalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the layered pane in a more modern application as that allows you to use a button, animations etc. E.g. in the case of the `FloatingActionButton` which seems similar to this that's what we do.

However, to answer the question you can just use `addPointerReleasedListener` on the form to detect and handle a touch event.

Comment: Thank you for the FloatingActionButton hint: it's really better and easier to use!